# Multi-Value Fields - Search Filter access

Tags: ms-access, vba

After extensive research i have yet to find the an answer to my problem. I am having a hard time with "Multi-Value" combobox field. I would like to be able to add this multi value combo box into my search form. But my code seems to not be working. My research tells me that the data of multivalue fields are stored somewhere else. Here is my code i hope i can get steered into the right direction.

For example the Color field is Multi-value dropdown :Red, blue, yellow
You can select more than one option so this field is different from my other fields. This code works perfect for all of my other fields. Please let me know what you think. Thanks

```
If Nz(Me.Color) <> "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "tblFlower.Color = '" & Me.Color & "'"
End If
```

Comment: Do you mean add a control, say a listbox, to a search form, which is populated with the options available in multi value?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a

Comment: TblFlower.color.value you'll need to use I believe

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you're talking about a listbox, not a combobox.

You need to iterate through selected items and add them to your where clause:

```
Dim ctl     As ListBox
Dim varItem As Variant

Set ctl = Me.Color

If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count >= 1 Then
    'write begining of strWhere clause
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND tblFlower.Color IN("

    'iterate throught selected items to add them to the list)
    For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
        strWhere = strWhere & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
    Next varItem

    'remove last comma and close parentheses
    strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 1)
    strWhere = strWhere & ")"
End If
```

this should add " AND tblFlower.Color IN('red','yellow')" to your strWhere string if you selected those 2 colors.

EDIT: for multiselect combobox

The value of the combobox is stored in an array. You need to iterate through this array:

```
Dim strWhere    As String
Dim i           As Integer

'first control if values have been selected
'then loop through array
If IsArray(Me.Color.Value) Then

    'write begining of strWhere clause
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND tblFlower.Color IN("

    For i = 0 To UBound(Me.Color.Value)
        strWhere = strWhere & "'" & Me.Color.Value(i) & "',"
    Next i

    'remove last comma and close parentheses
    strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 1) & ")"

End If
```

Comment: Its actually a combobox not a listbox. It is essentially a multiple select combo box: for example i have a tblFlower and a tblColor. tblColor has a list of the different colors red blue... tblFlower has a field called color and i linked that field to the tblcolor it created a dropdown and in the loup options i said Allow multiple selection

Comment: I've never used this feature before. I edited my answer with a piece of code for dealing with multi select combo boxes.

Comment: seems to not be working i don't know what i am doing wrong this is the type of field i have https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-multivalued-fields-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31?CorrelationId=864bb826-b28b-40fb-8b74-2e45d38d40fd&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM7 the problem is i dont know how to get access or reference these fields in an if statments. I also posted a previous question on mandatory fields but stilll no solution. These Multi valued fields are really giving me a hard time.